Signin with Apple with MAUI
I have a MAUI project which uses Web Authenticator. Everything is fine if I use Web Authenticator only (Google, MS, Apple).
I used this tutorial.
If I use the following code for signing in on iOS 13+ everything seems to work, but the authUrl will never triggered. I have no Idea how to pass an authUrl to  AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync().
var scheme = "..."; // Apple, Microsoft, Google, Facebook, etc.
var authUrlRoot = "https://example.org/mobileauth/";
WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;

if (scheme.Equals("Apple")
    && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS
    && DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
{
    // Use Native Apple Sign In API's
    result = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync();
}
else
{
    // Web Authentication flow
    var authUrl = new Uri($"{authUrlRoot}{scheme}");
    var callbackUrl = new Uri("myapp://");

    result = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
}

var authToken = string.Empty;

if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out string name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    authToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";

if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out string email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    authToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";

// Note that Apple Sign In has an IdToken and not an AccessToken
authToken += result?.AccessToken ?? result?.IdToken;

Maybe I misunderstand something.

Apple Sign-In on iOS 13+ uses ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider, which handles everything natively. You don’t need to pass an authUrl because the native APIs already manage the authorization flow. Apple authenticates the user by Apple ID and it returns an IdToke, name and email (last 2 might not always come).
Might want to check the configuration of Apple’s OpenID Connect implementation:  https://account.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.
Hope this helps.
